# Why isn't the child Flexcard being updated with new data in the pubsub event?

Tags: omnistudio

I have added a child card to my flexcard, equipped with a pubsub event listener that responds to the "card set value" event. Upon execution, this event is triggered and successfully sets the expected value. However, the Flexcard UI data does not reflect the update. I attempted to address this by setting up a card reload event, but the UI still does not display the new data.

I'm perplexed by this situation. Can you offer any insights into why my child Flexcard isn't being updated with the new data? To better illustrate the "set value" event, you can view

[image: Child flex card data not updated]

Answer (score 0):

However, upon further investigation, I've discovered that the hindrance to Pubsub event listeners updating event-related data in the UI.

In reference to the OmniStudio documentation, the key lies in utilizing the dynamic event registration based on either **{Parent.attr}** or **{Session.var}**. These context variables play a pivotal role in updating the UI as intended. By incorporating them, I've achieved the desired results.

Your assistance and suggestions have been immensely valuable throughout this troubleshooting process. Your time and effort in analyzing my issue are greatly appreciated.

You may check the Omnistudio [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_add_an_event_listener_to_a_flexcard_38031.htm&type=5) for more detail

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_add_an_event_listener_to_a_flexcard_38031.htm&type=5

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the actions you took in more detail? I have kind of the same issue. I want to display data to the child flexcard datatable based on the parent datatable selection.